# Determine bijectivity of a linear map from matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Define two linear maps $L: \mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbf{R}^3$ and $K :\mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbf{R}^3$ such that $$L = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && 2 && 0 \\ 1 &&0 && 3 \end{bmatrix} \text{ and } KL = \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 2 && 3 \\ 2 && 4 && 0 \\ 4 &&6 && 9 \end{bmatrix}$$ Why is $K$ a bijection? Determine the map $K$.

How can I get any information about $K$ here? I cannot just determine it from the product, right? For $L$ I have that $\det(L) = 4 \ne 0$, thus at least $L$ is bijective.

Answer (score 3):

From $KL = \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 2 && 3 \\ 2 && 4 && 0 \\ 4 &&6 && 9 \end{bmatrix}$ we get, since $L$ is invertible:

$$K=KLL^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 && 2 && 3 \\ 2 && 4 && 0 \\ 4 &&6 && 9 \end{bmatrix} \cdot L^{-1}.$$

Hence compute $L^{-1}$ and then

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 && 2 && 3 \\ 2 && 4 && 0 \\ 4 &&6 && 9 \end{bmatrix} \cdot L^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$L$ is as you said bijective. So is $KL$. As

$$K = (KL) L^{-1},$$

$K$ is also a bijection (the composition of two bijections is a bijection).